# Problems publishing a website on smarterasp.net with csc.exe file included?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, I built a simple website with a C# contact form.
When I compile and run on localhost it works perfectly fine. However, when I try to publish it (on smarterasp.net) I am getting an error:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
>
> [ExternalException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "..\bin\roslyn\csc.exe"

I have contacted smarterasp.net and they said they dont allow .exe files. I tried to delete csc.exe with ftp from the server but when I do that I am getting the error:

> Could not find file "..\bin\roslyn\csc.exe".

How can I solve this issue with the csc.exe that is trying to get included in my project so I can get my this website published?

Comment: What do you publish to your hoster? What kind of files? What kind of VS project did you use? How did you publish it? You normally do not ship csc to your webserver.

Comment: It's an MVC project containing html,css,js,cshtml,c#. etc. i published it using the Wed Deploy from within visual studio.

Comment: Hmm.... Do they allow .exe file? This is important. If they allow it, you just need to ask them to give the permission for you. Your applicaiton should be working.

Comment: Just change permissions to Read-Write for the /bin folder.  Thanks, GuChil for the answer.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

After hours of researching i came up with the solution.

Since the .NET 4.5 version, Roslyn compilation is the default way of compiling. This means if you create any web application either Web Forms or MVC using .NET 4.5 you get this Roslyn csc.exe compilation pre-installed in your project.

Basically what i needed was to compile and deploy my project without Roslyn or any .exe files on it.

So here is the Solution that worked for me. You can deploy without Roslyn with no change in code:

1. Open NuGet Package Manager window
2. uninstall **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform** package and rebuild & republish. (This uninstallation also removes CodeDom configuration from web.config file.)

This will solve your purpose. Basically this will not generate any csc.exe, vbc.exe files inside bin folder.

I hope it works for you too!

Comment: In your control panel, there is an option under "Security Manager" to "Allow .EXE Files". That at least fixes the upload problem.

Comment: Cool! I was chatting with them they said they don't support .EXE files. I guess they don't know what they support.

Comment: @aethercowboy I tried the option to allow exe files, but it didn't work. I still got the "cannot execute a program" exception. Setting write permissions on the directory and the trust level to Full may have fixed it as well. But removing the Roslyn compiler seemed much simpler, and it worked!! Thanks a ton!

Comment: You just saved me from a sleepless night. Thank you

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me too.

Comment: After doing this you will no longer be able to use C# 6.0 language features in Razor (.cshtml) files...

Comment: I think @Eris has the "right" answer below.  It doesn't just hide the symptoms but addresses the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me endless headaches.

Comment: Great stuff!  Thank you

Answer (score 20):

I had this issue on Smarter ASP. On the browser file manager in the control panel, navigate to 'Roslyn' folder in bin and set .net permission to read/write. It worked then.

Answer (score 17):

If you actually want to keep the roslyn codegen, you just need to set the permissions on the application's bin folder to allow the ApplicationPool user Read & Execute.

I did this using the explorer Security tab on the folder properties dialog, but you should also be able to do something like:

```
icacls PATH_TO_SERVICE_BIN /grant "ApplicationPoolUser":(OI)(CI)RX
```

Comment: I needed to grant IIS_IUSRS Read on the project site, Read & Execute on the bin. (I just gave it Read & Execute on the entire project site, but that's only for local use.)  Thank you!

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer.  This solves the problem at its root, it doesn't just hide the symptoms.

Answer (score 13):

I found the solution as unchecking "Allow precompiled site to be updatable", on publish window.
[image]

Comment: This won't work if your ASP.NET site relies on the `App_Code` folder. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484888/the-directory-website-app-code-is-not-allowed-because-the-application-is-pre) for more information.

Comment: Unchecking the "allow precompiled site" box was what finally did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: This works only for websites, but not for web applications

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect for me. I needed DotNetCompilerPlatform, because of  C# 6 (Null-conditional Operators), but I am using Godaddy shared hosting :(

Answer (score 12):

Just remove the codedom section from the Web.config, this solves the problem.

Answer (score 12):

Just set rw access for `/bin` folder in Smarterasp.net File Manager as shown below, restart your app

[image: See this image for details]

Comment: **It does work**. But you have to buy .NET Premium hosting plan in order to run "*.exe" files, like "csc.exe" (Roslyn).

Comment: My current plan is "Advance Plan" and it works. Prev plan is Basic, next is Premium, so currently I can't confirm your point

Comment: You are absolutly right. I've noticed that each [hosting plan](https://image.prntscr.com/image/s74j22qiTnOk02mcpxl6NQ.png) (FREE as well) supports **Full Trust**. Well, it was just a **file permission** issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Just experienced the same issue as the OP when publishing an ASP.net 4.5.2 SPA via web deploy in VS2015.

The solution I found to work was to remove the Nuget package **"Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform"**.

You could, alternatively, simply remove the **system.codedom compiler config** section from your **Web.config** file, which would have the same affect.

Comment: Thanks, nice one bro!

Comment: If I do that, all that happens is that the build won't work and it gives me a ton of error messages saying things like: `error CS0103: The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got it working:

1. In your control panel, navigate to Security Manager > Allow .EXE Files
2. Set the value to On (this will let you upload .exe files)
3. In your `Web.config`, set full trust (this will let you run them)

   ```
   <configuration> 
     <system.web> 
       <trust level="Full" /> 
     </system.web> 
   </configuration>
   ```
4. In your publish settings, enable "Precompile during publishing", but in the 
   Advanced Precompile Settings (the Configure link next to this option), disable "Allow precompiled site to be updateable".

Comment: This solution looks ok, but shall i turn off exe upload after publish? as it can be a security issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I solved it by enable the permissions of the hosting directory (read/write/delete).

Comment: At least give us a hint of how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need SmarterAsp.Net to allow the uploading of an .exe file to support the features and functionality of your website, you can.  Just go to the control panel and turn on "Allow .Exe Files"  See below:

[image]

In my case I had to do this because I wanted to host an Asp.Net Core website and that absolutely requires an .exe file :-)

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** Ensure that csc.exe is not zero bytes in size.

---

**Longer answer**

To add yet another cause and solution: In my case, I got this Yellow Screen Of Death in my browser:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 255.
>
> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\roslyn\csc.exe
>   /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+ ...
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.2558.0

Upon investigation, I isolated the call to csc.exe by executing it inside a  CMD window:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\roslyn\csc.exe
```

I got this message box:

[image]

followed by this line in the CMD window:

> Access is denied.

Upon inspecting the files in Windows File Explorer I found out that csc.exe had a size of zero bytes.

I'm unsure at which stage of my deployment script this happens, but after replacing the 0-byte-sized csc.exe with an actual working one, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions did not work for me and are not correct, since roslyn is not optional these days.

What worked was ensuring that the pool account had **read & execute** permissions on the **root folder** of the web application. You can find the account to grant this permission to by finding the Pool name your web app uses, then Application Pool -> ***pool name*** -> Advanced Settings -> Identity.

My VPS host uses non-standard directories for hosting as follows:

`c:\home\web.app.name\wwwroot`

The ***web.app.name*** folder needed the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the nuget package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` to the latest version (at that time) `2.0.1` resolved this issue for me without having to grant permissions to the folder or remove the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this due to a 3rd party application. MalwareBytes Anti-Ransomeware was actually the culprit that was blocking access. Resolved this with:

- Right-click systray icon for MalwareBytes Anti-Ransomeware  (not anti-exploit)
- Stop Protection