# IIS Error On Adding Managed Local HttpModule: Can not Execute a program

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am running asp.net website on IIS 10 and I wrote a HttpModule in a class.
when I add this module in IIS, I have this error:

Add Managed Module:
There was an err while performing this operation
Cannot execute program. The command being executed was 'c:...\bin\roselyn\csc.exe' /shared /keepalive:"10" /noconfig/fullpathes @'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\ranework64\v4.0.30310\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\u8mj01d2\qwerty.cmdline'

Comment: Try to set the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to true in iis advanced settings. Open the IIS -> select Application Pools -> Advanced Settings -> Enable 32-Bit Applications  to True.

Comment: @samwu sorry, this solution does not solve the problem

Comment: can you post more information about your HttpModule in a class?

Comment: @samwu that is based on this article:
[link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/akkiraju/url-rewriting-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: You can try the solution in this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427195/iis-7-error-cannot-execute-a-program-the-command-being-executed-was-csc-exe-a/43547793](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427195/iis-7-error-cannot-execute-a-program-the-command-being-executed-was-csc-exe-a/43547793).

Comment: Does this err happens even when you click on the first node in IIS Connections which is the name of your computer?

Comment: @EhsanAbidi There is no error in this case

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: support.microsoft.com.

Comment: @samwu FYI, the workaround to this problem is writing module tag manually in web.config instead of selecting module from module list in IIS.

Comment: I'm receiving the same error. I'm testing application initialization settings to figure out why we're having downtime and not a true overlapped recycle, so I'm trying to add the application initialization module, but getting stuck at this error that prevents the list of modules from being populated.  Windows 10, with latest updates.

Note that this error occurs only for web applications under the website, but works without error when choosing modules for the website itself.